# Как сохранить состояние фрагмента, когда вызывется FragmentTransaction.detach()?

Tags: android

Написал приложение с вкладками, используя [этот мануал](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#newTab()). Столкнулся с проблемой, что когда переключаются вкладки, не вызывается onSavedInstanseState фрагмента на текущей вкладке, и, соответственно, ничего не восстанавливается, когда я перехожу обратно. Как быть?

P.S. Просьба модераторов удалить [такой же вопрос, заданный ранее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/99390/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-fragmenttransaction-detach) - его, по ходу дела, никто не увидел.

Answer (score 1):

Все проще, чем ожидалось:

```
LinkedList<String>  savedDevicesNames = null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (D) { Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated"); }

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedDevicesNames != null) {
        for (String deviceNameAddr : savedDevicesNames) {
            adapter.add(deviceNameAddr);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    savedDevicesNames = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        savedDevicesNames.add(adapter.getItem(i));
    }
}
```